# How to print SASS variables for debugging

Tags: visual-studio-code, sass

In order to see which variable I'm currently using, I need to print them to the compressed file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this regex in VS-Code for **regular** variables:

```
((\$.*);.*)
```

and replace it with

```
$1/*! Variable is: $2 */
```

Use this regex in VS-Code for **interpolated** variables:

```
(#\{(\$.*)\}.*)
```

and replace it with

```
$1/*! Variable is: $2 */
```